# Got stuck in scraping information from bunch of tags

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

Trying to extract the information which is surrounded by  bunch of tags similar to the attached one. The data is in the place  of "Comedy Nights live - Full Episodes". I used

```
response.xpath("//h3/span/text()").extract()
response.xpath('//*[@id="meta"]/h3/span/text()').extract()
```

queries to get extracted but every time I got an empty list. There may be some mistakes in accessing data through commands but, being a beginner, I need guidance about how can I reach the required goal.

```
<a id="meta" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-grid-playlist-renderer" href="/watch?v=q1XwumKHSg8&amp;list=PLX18mvVSh-bz3qlgf-uomp8zktOG5Rdj3">
  <h3 class="style-scope ytd-grid-playlist-renderer">
      <span id="video-title" class="style-scope ytd-grid-playlist-renderer">
        Comedy Nights Live - Full Episodes
    </span>
  </h3>
</a>
```

Here is the spider file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class YtubeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ytube'
    allowed_domains = ['www.youtube.com/user/KapilComedyNights/playlists']
    start_urls = ['http://www.youtube.com/user/KapilComedyNights/playlists/']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

scrapy,python 2.7!

Comment: Both of those should work, it looks like there is another problem. If you post your actual code, we can probably help figure out what that problem is.

Comment: Should I post spider file?

Comment: @stranac edited!

Comment: Looks like you're not getting the page you think you are. If you remove the trailing backslash from the start url, you will get a page that actually contains data you want (although the html structure is a bit different from what you've shown in the question)

Comment: Also, `allowed_domains` should only contain domains (e.g. `youtube.com`), not entire URLs.

Comment: @stranac I really appreciate your time but I don't think that I'm getting wrong page. Will you explain a little more about what you just suggested!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are. The url `http://www.youtube.com/user/KapilComedyNights/playlists/` gives you the home page of the channel, while `http://www.youtube.com/user/KapilComedyNights/playlists` gives you the playlists page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your browser Developer Tools how the page is composed. You will see  Youtube is using AJAX. Download the ajax data directly and parse them. Also be aware scrapy access to the site anonymously.

Try turnoff ajax=0:

https://www.youtube.com/user/KapilComedyNights/playlists/?ajax=0&app=desktop

You get different response:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="yt-lockup-ontent"]/h3/a/@title').extract()  
[u'Comedy - Full Episodes', 
u'Comedy - Audio', 
u'Comedy Nights Live', 
u'Comedy Nights with Kapil - Shorts',  
u'Comedy Nights Live - Full Episodes',  
u'COMEDY NIGHTS LIVE - FULL EPISODES',  
u'Comedy Nights Bachao',  
u'COMEDY NIGHTS BACHAO - FULL EPISODES',  
u'Comedy Nights Bachao - Full Episodes']
```